# Repeating a vector function and storing into matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a function which creates a row vector(N) up to a specified number of N columns. This vector is generated by have the next column add a random integer between 1 and 5 to the previous column and keeps on going until column N. However, I wish to generate the function vector(200) 500 times, where each row vector is randomly generated, and then store each of these vector into a matrix of size 500x200.

I am currently a beginner and I'm just testing Matlab out.

What I tried to do is:

> for r=1:500
>
> row(r) = vector(200)
>      mat(r, :) = row(r)
>
> end

However this does not seem to work. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the *first* column is also a random number between 1 and 5, you can do this

```
result = cumsum(randi(5, 500, 200), 2);
```

*How it works*: `randi(5, 500, 200)` generates `500`x`200` random integers between `1` and `5`; and `cumsum(..., 2)` gives the cumulative sum along each row.

Comment: Thanks! That is a lot simpler than what I was doing.